# As a Philippine passport holder, can I transfer from Heathrow terminal five to three without a visa?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, lhr, filipino-citizens

I would like to know if I need a transit visa if I transfer from Heathrow terminal 5 to three. I will only be staying there two hours as I will be flying to Geneva. I am a Philippine passport holder.

Answer (score 9):

If your transit time is less than 24 hours and you are from the Philipines, you will not need a transit visa as long as you will stay in the arrival/departure lounge. This is called airside transit. If you need to go out from this lounge or need to stay more than 24 hours then you will need a visa.

In your case (from the Philippine, 2 hours connection time), [UK border agency website](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/do-you-need-a-visa/) says:

> **Yes, you generally need a visa to transit the UK
>   (unless you will arrive in the UK by air, and leave the UK by air less than 24 hours later)**

In addition to that, Heathrow airport has a nice service for transit passengers. [Heathrow airport website](http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/flight-connections/terminal-5-international-connecting-to-terminal-3-international) describes how to transfer from terminal 5 to 3 without the need to pass through passport control.

Comment: so to make things clear, its safe to say that i dont need a visa right?

Comment: ty very much for the help!